# foreach command in Stata

Tags: foreach, panel, stata

I am using panel data, where the variable `countrynum` is the country number for 138 countries and `icr` is the independent variable. To conduct a poolability test I have to run the below code to get the variables `icr_1`,  `icr_2`, `icr_3` ... `icr_138`.

However, the code only generates `icr_1`. Can someone help me understand why? I need all 138 variables.

```
xi, prefix(C) i.countrynum

gen Ccountrynum_1=1 if countrynum==1

replace Ccountrynum_1=0 if countrynum!=1

foreach var of varlist icr {
    foreach num of numlist 1(1)138{
        gen `var'_`num'=`var'* Ccountrynum_`num' 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some things in your code that I would do differently, but I don't see anything that brings up an error. Rather than debugging code I think it's more useful to suggest an easier way for what you seem to be doing:

```
separate icr, by(countrynum)
```

`xi` is an older command which has been superseded by factor variable notation, so you only need `xi` in case you're using an older command that doesn't support this, which I think is not the case here.

To do a poolability test as I understand it you can run a regression with `i.countrynum` like this:

```
reg y x1 x2 x... i.countrynum
testparm i.countrynum
```

The output of `testparm` will tell you whether the country dummies are jointly significant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow this easily. Let's first note that

```
gen Ccountrynum_1=1 if countrynum==1
replace Ccountrynum_1=0 if countrynum!=1
```

simplifies to

```
gen Ccountrynum_1 = countrynum == 1
```

That said, the double loop

```
foreach var of varlist icr {
    foreach num of numlist 1(1)138{
        gen `var'_`num'=`var'* Ccountrynum_`num' 
    }
}
```

simplifies to a single loop

```
forval num = 1/138 {
    gen icr_`num' = icr * Ccountrynum_`num' 
}
```

That said, it's hard to understand why that code should be expected to work as you only explain the generation of `Ccountrynum_1`.

It's really unusual to need that number of extra variables. In addition to @Wouter Wakker's suggestion, `tabulate, generate()` allows generation of indicator variables without a loop for whenever they are essential.